# Ionic : Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

When running `the cordova build android`  command i get this error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

When i tried running this command a few days ago it made the apk, but now it won't anymore. i didn't change anything either

i tried running ionic cordova resources again so that maybe it wouldn't chrash on the image again

Does anyone else have this issue? What causes this?

full stacktrace:

```
PS C:\school\pokemontest> cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\school\pokemontest\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-pioort-xhdpi: Error: Invalid resource directory name
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
C:\school\pokemontest\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-pioort-xhdpi: Error: Invalid resource directory name
20 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 19 up-to-date


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
C:\school\pokemontest\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\school\pokemontest\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-pioort-xhdpi: Error: Invalid resource directory name

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: Just check my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499053/ionic-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources#comment119749535_60675883

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem.
I deleted the plugin and platform map.
After that i ran the commands `cordova prepare` for the plugins
and `cordova build android` to set everything up again.

Answer (score 11):

After a lot of tries, I fix this issue by doing

1- Open the config.xml

2- Change xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" of the widget tag to xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

3- Rebuild the project

Comment: Entire line should look like this: `<widget id="com.xxx.xxx" version="1.1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`. then do platform rm and add.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running command `cordova clean android && cordova build android`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Four Ange is correct but I just wanted to provide a little more explanation. This is an xml issue, more specifically an xml namespace issue. If you add this to your `config.xml` file:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
</edit-config>
```

you have to add the an xml namespace called `android` namespace on the because of the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` attribute (specifically the `android:` part). If you don't you basically have a poorly formatted xml document. The error given doesn't say anything about that, which is unfortunate.

The solution to that, as noted in the answer, is to declare the `android` namespace inside the `widget` tag like this:

```
<widget
    id="org.collegeforward.portal"
    version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
```

That tells the xml parser that the `usesCleartextTraffic` is part of the `android` namespace. Of course since nobody uses XML anymore (partly because of issues like this) this is basically not that relevant to the world today. But if you're curious like me, you enjoy knowing why things work the way they do or why they break the way they do.